# Python script for SVG to PNG conversion with Extjs

Tags: python, extjs, charts, extjs4.1

I'm trying to save a chart by converting SVG to PNG with a Python script. 
So I start storing the svg data in a variable with :

```
var svgdata = Ext.draw.engine.SvgExporter.generate(chart.surface);
```

When I do `alert(svgdata)`, I can see that this output is correct.

But when I send it to the server like this :

```
Ext.draw.engine.ImageExporter.defaultUrl = "data/svg_to_png.py?svgdata="+svgdata;
```

The svgdata that has been sent looks like this :

```
<?xml version=
```

I'm new to extjs, please help me on this one. What is the right way to send svg data to my python script and render a png image ?

This is my python script :

```
import cairo
import cgi
import rsvg
print "Content-type: image/png\n\n"

arguments = cgi.FieldStorage()
img =  cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, 640,480)
ctx = cairo.Context(img)
handler= rsvg.Handle(None, str(arguments["svgdata"]))
handler.render_cairo(ctx)
img.write_to_png("svg.png")
```

HELP ME PLEASE!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <iframe id="file_download_iframe" src="blank.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

You will need a blank html page on your server for this to work properly in all browsers.  Basically the blank.html page is an empty page to satisfy that the ifram always has a page in it.

Then you need a basic form hidden somewhere too:

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <form
        id = "file_download_iframe_form"
        name = "file_download_iframe_form"
        target = "file_download_iframe"
        method = "post"
        action = "data/svg_to_png.py"
    >
        <input type="hidden" id="svgdata" name="svgdata"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Then have a javascript function like this:

```
function getImage(svgdata){
    var form = document.getElementById("file_download_iframe_form");
    document.getElementById("svgdata").value = svgdata;
    form.submit();
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it's telling me `The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.`. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I can show you a way to do it without the imageexporter if that's okay, as for that class I am not familiar with how to use it.

Comment: How can I send the svg data to be processed ? It's crazy that there are not so many threads about this, or maybe I am missing something... Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: not really an extjs solution, but one that I know works anyway.

Comment: I have implemented your solution, but now I have this error : `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/png`. I assume it's because of the header in my python script, but the header seems correct... Any ideas please?

Comment: I'm not sure what causes that issue as we do not experience it, but we set all our downloads to response.setContentType("application/unknown"); and response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + yourFilename);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29373/discussion-between-user1734229-and-reimius)